# Multiple instances of the same React component type do not render correctly

Tags: reactjs

I'm a newbie React developer. I'm trying to make a component that takes a list of information (i.e. the InfoList.currentList in the code below.) and renders it as multiple  elements. To help my model code trigger re-render, the component in question registers a trigger function using useReducer(). Here's my minimized code (still producing the same issue.)

```js
function BannerStyleInfoView() {
  function reducer(state: {[index: number]: any}, action: any) {
    return InfoList.currentList()
  }

  const [currentList, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {})
  useEffect(function() {
    InfoList.forceRender = () => {dispatch(undefined)}
    return () => {InfoList.forceRender = undefined}
  }, [])

  const elements = Object.entries(currentList).map(function([index, entry]) {
    // @ts-ignore
    const {text} = entry
    console.debug("=== Added", index, text)
    return (
        <BannerStyleInfoElement key={index} index={index} text={text} />
    )
  })
  console.log("=== elements:", elements)

  return (
    <>
      {elements}
    </>
  )
}
```

```js
function BannerStyleInfoElement({index, text}: {index: string, text: string}) {
  console.debug("=== show:", index, text)
  return (
      <div key={index}> {text} </div>
  )
}
```

```js
class InfoList {
  public static initialize() {
    infoList = {}
  }

  public static append(text:string, duration: number = 2) {
    const entry = {
      duration,
      text,
      timestamp: Date.now()
    }
    let indexString
    indexString = nextIdentifier.toString()
    ++nextIdentifier
    infoList[indexString] = entry

    if (InfoList.forceRender) {
      InfoList.forceRender()
    }

    return indexString
  }

  public static clear(identifier: string) {
    console.assert(identifier in infoList)
    delete infoList[identifier]
  }

  public static currentList() {
    return infoList
  }

  public static forceRender: (() => void) | undefined
}
export {InfoList}


let nextIdentifier = 0
let infoList: {[index: string]: any} = {}
```

In the code above, I invoked `InfoList.append()` twice. When it was first invoked, the code correctly emits one `<div>`. But the second call does not re-render. The log message is like below.

```
=== Added 0 entry0
=== elements: [{…}]
=== show: 0 entry0

=== Added 0 entry0
=== Added 1 entry1
=== elements: (2) [{…}, {…}]
```

My observation is there's no `=== show` log message by the second call, while the first call correctly emits the log message. I suspected it's related to handling multiple instances of the same component type, but I'm not sure. I added `key` property, but it's still not working. Any advice?

Thanks,

DK

Answer (score 0):

I found that my reducer returns a global object and it caused a problem. That is, React stores my global object, the object is updated by another code, but reducer returns the same object address which causes React to conclude the object has remained the same.